# Making Magento themes from scratch. Do's and Dont's?

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm trying very diligently to learn the inner workings of magento, I've watched many video tutorials, read many blog articles and tutorials, and am somewhat getting the hang of it. The only problem i'm running into is I can only find tutorials and videos that are based on versions too old to use as a reference.

I built an HTML shopping cart template. I'm having trouble figuring out where to start in creating a new theme to base it on.

Do I copy the default app and skin folders and modify things? I attempted that, couldn't figure it out.

I'm asking if anyone has any in depth resources for the new 1.7 magento, about theming from scratch and working with the files, blocks, and layouts.

I have a degree in programming, however i'm not used to this version of MVC.

Looking for tips, pointers, books, tutorials, screencasts, anything to help me build a modern magento theme.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

same issue with me earlier , please check this: http://dbhoopendra.blogspot.in/2012/05/layouts.html#.UYibfKLDDRB